# Problemas Logo plugin mercadopago en virtuemart- Joomla

Tags: php, mercadopago, joomla3

Buen dia, tengo una tienda virtual en joomla con virtuemart, incorporte el plugin de mercadopago, tengo dos metodos de pago contraentrega y mercadopago, el problema es que no me sale el logo de mercadopago, pero si el de contraentrega, que estaria mal??

---

No, no lo tengo de esa forma, lo que tengo es un plugin de mercado pago, no se como hacer lo que me indicas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se renderiza el código html con la etiqueta <img> ? Si es así, la url de la imagen es accesible?

Comment: Favor que muestres los codigos, asi ayudaría a ver cual error de código que hiciste hasta ahora. Sigue el ejemplo en este enlace: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ] Saludos!

Comment: Este curso te será de utilidad: https://www.acamica.com/cursos/105/la-api-mercadolibre-conceptos-finales y este otro también! https://www.acamica.com/cursos/62/introduccion-a-la-api-de-mercadolibre Saludos :D